# D3: cannot load json data from database using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I have my D3 code in `main.js` to load data from a PHP script `get_data.php` and display it using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). After loading this initial table, all rows are assigned a class `.data-cell`, which I bind with a click-listener that loads a second table using another PHP script `get_secondary_data.php`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    d3.json('../php/get_data.php', function (data) {

        console.log(data);  // first console log output

        var rows = add_row(data);
        var cells = add_cell(rows); // draw cells and add class data-cell to each

        $('#data-table').DataTable();

        d3.selectAll('.data-cell').on('click', function (d) {
            // extract the data url
            console.log(d.data_url); // second console log output

            // draw secondary table
            load_secondary_table(d.data_url);

        });
    });
});

function load_secondary_table(data_url) {
    d3.json('../php/get_secondary_data.php', function (secondary_data) {
        console.log(secondary_data); // third console log output

        // drawing secondary table logic
    });
}
```

The first script loads the data fine, and I can see the output of 1st console log. The second console log is also fine, I can see the data_url of the correct row that I click. However, the third console log output secondary_data as `null`.

I have run the second PHP script by itself and it returns the correct result. I have also checked the Chrome's Network tab and did see the correct JSON output in the response of the second PHP script. It just not gets loaded into my page.

May I know what's wrong?

Comment: your parameter of load_secondary_table is not used. Does get_secondary_data.php require something?

Comment: @Bernhard yes, it's supposed to be a param for the PHP script (which I don't know how to pass it in from D3). However, I hard code some value in the script just to see if the result is loaded.

Comment: are you sure you return valid json? copy the result of the second script to a json validator

Comment: @Bernhard argh, I found the issue, in my PHP I also echo some database connection debug log while I should only echo the final JSON. Now it's fine. Thank you. Please put your suggestion as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you return valid json?
Copy the result of the second script to a json validator